# Text overflows for custom cell painting of DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Here is my cell painting method.

```cs
DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;

if ( e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1 )
{ return; }
if ( ( grid.Rows [ e.RowIndex ].Cells [ e.ColumnIndex ].Value == null ) )
    return;

Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(GridList[0].GridColor),backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor);
Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush);

// Erase the cell.
e.Graphics.FillRectangle ( backColorBrush, e.CellBounds );

// Draw the grid lines (only the right and bottom lines;
// DataGridView takes care of the others).
e.Graphics.DrawLine ( gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1 );
e.Graphics.DrawLine ( gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom );

// Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment.
if ( e.Value != null )
{
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    Brush brush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    String s = (String)e.Value;

    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
    List<int> pos = null;
    if ( grid.Rows [ e.RowIndex ].Cells [ e.ColumnIndex ].Tag != null )
    {
        pos = ( List<int> ) grid.Rows [ e.RowIndex ].Cells [ e.ColumnIndex ].Tag;
    }

    String[] arr = s.Split('\n');
    SizeF stringSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, arr[0], e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size);

    float wid = stringSize.Height;
    int X,Y;

    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ( pos == null || pos.IndexOf ( i ) == -1 )
        {
            X = ( e.CellBounds.X );
            Y = ( e.CellBounds.Y + i * ( ( int ) stringSize.Height ) );
            TextRenderer.DrawText ( e.Graphics, arr [ i ], e.CellStyle.Font, new Point ( X, Y ), SystemColors.ControlText );
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(arr[i], e.CellStyle.Font, brush1, new PointF(X, Y), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
        else
        {
            X = ( e.CellBounds.X );
            Y = ( e.CellBounds.Y + i * ( int ) stringSize.Height );
            Brush brushForBox = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 120, 50,0));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle ( brushForBox, X, Y, e.CellBounds.Width, ( int ) stringSize.Height );
            TextRenderer.DrawText ( e.Graphics, arr [ i ], e.CellStyle.Font, new Point ( X, Y ), SystemColors.ControlText );
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(arr[i], e.CellStyle.Font, brush, new PointF(X, Y), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
    }
}
//grid.InvalidateCell(-1, e.RowIndex);
e.Handled = true;
```

Now it works fine, but the text overflows for the first and last cells. For example, if the first cell in the `dataGridView` is partially visible then the text is rendered in the row header. Similarly for the last cell in the row text flows out of it. Any suggestion/solution is appreciated.

Comment: Try to use the overload of DrawString or recommended (!)  DrawText with a target rectangle. Of course the text will now be cut off if it caN't be fit into the rectangle..

Comment: @TaW I have tried DrawString but does not work correctly for multiline text. And I did not get your point "DrawText with a target rectangle" can you please explain a bit. And just to let you know I wrote this to highlight a certain line of 
 text in datagridview cell.

Comment: @ArunPratap the question that you mentioned is for drawing thicker lines between two cells which is nowhere close to my problem. In my case, I have a text overflow problem. You should at least go through both the questions first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CellPainting` event will let you draw onto the **whole visible area** of the `DataGridView`, including all headers and excluding only scrollbars.

It does provide you with the `Cell`'s area in the `e.CellBounds` rectangle but it will still let you draw outside of it.

To restrict your drawing to the `Cell` the simplest way is to change the `e.Graphics.ClipBounds`to the cell's bounding rectangle; to make sure no overflow into the rowheaders can occur we restrict it to only start left of the rowheader, maybe like this:

```
int rhw = grid.RowHeadersWidth;
Rectangle clip = e.CellBounds;
if (e.CellBounds.X < rhw)
    clip = new Rectangle(rhw, clip.Y, clip.Width - rhw, clip.Height);
e.Graphics.SetClip(clip, CombineMode.Replace);
```

Now nothing you draw can overflow.

Notes:

- You could also set the target rectangle for for both [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h60yx8s5(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/19sb1bw6(v=vs.110).aspx),  but drawing in different fonts will make that a bit harder.
- For some reason the clipped region doesn't seem to work with `TextRenderer`.

Also note: I couldn't reproduce the effect of underflowing into the headers. I can imagine that it might come from the cell's top can lying in the negative if the top cell isn't quite fully visible. (My DGV only let's me scroll by integral rows, though.) To exclude these cases you may need to calculate a better clipping rectangle that only starts right below the header cells..

Comment: The underflow occurs for row Headers, not column headers. Indeed DGV only allows integral row scrolling but same is not true for columns. So when some of the cell's content is under row header and you hover above it just repaints the cell and not header(or some other way) and text from under the header become visible. And I can use e.ClipBounds but the problem with that is I can't find from which character I need to start my string.

Comment: Ah, got it. I have updated the answer to prevent the overflow. If find that the clipping does work correctly, ie the text is being clipped to the left.

Comment: On a side note CombineMode.Union works much better then Replace in my case I really didn't understand why though.

Comment: Hm, that sounds wrong. Good if it works, but it really shouldn't change the clipping region as the cell bounds is already included in the old ClipRegion.. - Also: What do you mean by 'works much better' ?

Comment: I suspect the fact that the TextRenderer doesn't follow is b/c GDI compatibility mode.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping` flag in your TextRenderer call should fix the issue for the RowHeaderCell overlap.

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, arr[i], e.CellStyle.Font, new Point(X, Y), SystemColors.ControlText, TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
```

No need to play around with `SetClip()` (which didn't work for me).