# How to Remove the Column grid lines and Column Hover when mouse is near

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

As you can see on the image, I want to remove those column grid lines in my `DataGridView` and that default hover of datagridview column. I tried different things on datagridview properties but nothing happen. I'm doing these because i don't like the way it look like. I hope someone would be able to help me.

[image]

Comment: Draw the lines yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118206/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Great ! Thank you

Comment: Implement you own paint method and in that just don't paint grid lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441885/text-overflows-for-custom-cell-painting-of-datagridview/51473848#51473848 look at this question and adjust the paint method according to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the following properties of `DataGridView` in designer:

- [`ColumnHeadersBorderStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersborderstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2)  → None
- [`EnableHeadersVisualStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) → false
- [`ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersdefaultcellstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2) → Set custom header `BackColor`, increase the `Padding`

For more customization, you can handle [CellPainint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=netframework-4.7.2) event and check if `e.RowIndex==-1`, draw the column and at last set `e.Handled = true` to stop applying default paint to the column. You can see an example describing about some details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53827259/3110834).